# How can I delete my Skype account?

Tags: account-management, skype-for-web

I have created new Skype account, and would like to permanently delete the old one I had.

I tried with godelete.com and justdelete but nothing.

How do I delete a Skype account?

Answer (score 2):

[From the Skype FAQs:](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA142/can-i-delete-my-skype-account)

"If you no longer want to use your Skype account, you first need to remove all your personal information from your profile... If you want us to remove your Skype Name from the Skype directory, you need to contact our Skype Customer Service. It may take up to two weeks to remove your name from the directory."

Following that guide will prevent your information from being searchable. Unfortunately, it seems that a Skype account can't be entirely deleted.

Answer (score 1):

From Skype Help: [I have more than one Skype account](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA142/how-do-i-close-my-skype-account):

> If you have two or more Skype accounts and you want to keep just one account, that's fine – we'll close the duplicate account(s) for you.
>
> Remember, when we close your account, everything associated with it – including contacts, purchases and history – will be lost. Make sure you've used up any Skype Credit you have, and cancelled any subscriptions or recurring payments. It’s also a good idea to **export your contacts** and **conversation history** if you want to transfer them to a new account.
>
> [Close a duplicate account](https://login.skype.com/login?return_url=https%3a%2f%2fsupport.microsoft.com%2fen-us%2fskype%3flanguage%3den%26locale%3dEN-US%26oaspworkflow%3dstart_1.0.0.0%26wfname%3dskype%26needslogin%3dtrue%26ccsid%3d636126410642513468&partner_id=3fdb6f9f635903ab490938ed648376bb&token=51f7cdad-bf51-44f1-8536-1a2daafb83cb)
>
> You'll be asked to sign in if you're not already. Select *Account and Password*, then *Closing an account*, and then click *Next* to chat to a customer support representative.